# Multiple font types in navigation drawer - Navigation component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[Navigation drawer items with different fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA5k3.png)

App theme's font not applying to some items in navigation drawer

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you.

Comment: Which part of the code can help to solve the problem? Im using NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);                 to setup navigation drawer                                                                                  Did you see the image in the question?